# Hover images with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I have CSS as below. Hovering works fine with 2 images, however the 3rd won't display inside the other two images. 3rd image is displaying below the first image.
I am trying to get 3 images hover simultaneously.

CSS

```
.card {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.card .img-top {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    width:200px;
 }

 .card:hover .img-top {
    display: inline;
 }

 .card:hover2 .img-top2 {
    display: inline;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="card">
     <img style="width: 200px; display: inline;" src="../media2/white" border="1">
     <img class="img-top" alt="Huifkar" src="../media2/red " border="1">
     <img class="img-top2" alt="baai" src="../media2/heerenbaai_paars.jpg" border="1">
</div>
```

Comment: You making div with `display: inline` that's not convenient, use `span` instead. 
I did not get why you making the `div` containing `image` as `display: inline` 

please make your question clear.

Comment: thank you. I am trying to get 1 basic picture, then hover over with mouse to picture 2, then picture 3 and if the mouse moves away: back to number 1. I can manage it with 2 pictures, not with 3

Comment: then its better to inject some js too,  `add a class with display block on hover` from `js`

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clearly stated.

However, Make the z-index of picture 3 higher and It should work properly.

```
    .card:hover2 .img-top2 {

        display: inline;
         z-index: 100;

    }
```